# Differential of a differential form without local coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

Given a differential form $w$ on a manifold, I know how to calculate $dw$ in local coordinates. But is there any way to define $dw$ independent of local coordinates?

Comment: It is the unique extension of differentiation of functions $d:C^{\infty}(M)\to\Omega^1(M)=\Gamma(T^*M)$ to a derivation of the graded-commutative algebra $\Omega^*(M)$. To define the differentiation of function, you don't need local coordinates.

Comment: To write down an explicit formula for $d\omega$, you need coordinates, but the point is that the expression behaves well under a change of coordinates.

Comment: You actually *don't* need coordinates. Look at the section titled "invariant formula" in the wikipedia page. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative#Exterior_derivative_in_local_coordinates

Answer (score 3):

A differential $k$-form on a smooth manifold $M$ is a skew-symmetric $C^{\infty}(M)$-linear map $\omega :\Gamma(TM)^k \to C^{\infty}(M)$. The exterior derivative of $\omega$ is a skew-symmetric $C^{\infty}(M)$-linear map $d\omega : \Gamma(TM)^{k+1} \to C^{\infty}(M)$ where $d\omega(V_0, \dots, V_k)$ is equal to

$$\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^iV_i(\omega(V_0, \dots, \hat{V_i}, \dots, V_k)) + \sum_{i<j}(-1)^{i+j}\omega([V_i, V_j], V_0, \dots, \hat{V_i}, \dots, \hat{V_j}, \dots, V_k).$$

In the above formula, the notation $\hat{V_i}$ is used to indicate that $V_i$ has been omitted.

As you can see, this formula does not require local coordinates.